# How to aggregate initialize with variadic indices?

Tags: c++, variadic, aggregate-initialization

Given the following struct with an underlying aggregate:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Array
{
    T data[N];
};
```

I'm trying to write another struct that takes variadic size_t templates and initializes a data member based on the struct above:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Indices>
struct MyClass
{   
    Array<size_t, sizeof...(Indices)> array{Indices...};
};
```

However, when I do:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<float, 1> obj;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 In constructor 'constexpr MyClass<float, 1ul>::MyClass()':
13:8: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
 In function 'int main()':
21:23: note: synthesized method 'constexpr MyClass<float, 1ul>::MyClass()' first required here
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Code works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/572fc5d309420d74

Comment: I'm using the one on cpp.sh which seems to be GCC 4.9.2

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 is pretty old.  I would recommend you use a different compiler like the one I used at the link in my previous compiler or [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) or [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)